# How Github determines top-11 contributors that are shown at the repository front page?

Tags: github

If you open a popular Github repository that has many contributors, the front repository page shows only top-11 contributors with their avatars and links to their profiles.

I cannot understand how this list is formed and how is it sorted. It looks very similar to "people who've made the most commits to the main branch" but does not match exactly.

**Example 1:** https://github.com/JOSM/Mapillary

In front page, there are total 22 contributors, and top-11 are shown with avatars:

[image]

In contributors graph page https://github.com/JOSM/Mapillary/graphs/contributors, the order is a bit different. As for now (July 18) and for default ordering (by commit number in decreasing order and over whole history), only top-5 people match the order of avatars in the front page. Person #6 from the front page (*knikel*) is for some reason #12 in the graph page, and person #11 (*jpietri*) is missing at all. Order of the other contributors is apparently the same.

The avatars order is also definitely not the order of contributors with most additions (in this case even top-5 people do not match).

Also, the graph page shows only 19 contributions while the front page says that there are 22 of them.

**Example 2:** https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/

Only top-8 contributors from the front page match the order in https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/graphs/contributors.
Person #9 from the front page (*jonnybbb*) is at the 11th place in the graph page.

[The documentation about contributors](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/viewing-activity-and-data-for-your-repository/viewing-a-projects-contributors#troubleshooting-contributors) does not mention that top-11 list from the front page at all.

Does anyone have an idea how the list at the front page is formed and sorted?
And why some people can be shown as contributors in the front page but can be missing in the contributors graph?